# Will be held or would be held

Tags: grammar, word-usage

The teacher said that the exam **will be held** on March 20, 2021

The teacher said that the exam **would be held** on March 20, 2021

Which one is correct?

Comment: The first is correct only if the exam hasn't yet taken place. _Would be held_ could be used if the teacher made an announcement in the past about an exam which _at the time_ had not yet happened.

Comment: Both are fine if *time of utterance* is before March 20 (i.e. - it's still meaningful to talk about when the exam *will* be held). But only past tense ***would*** is acceptable if we're looking at something reported after the exam has taken place. And native speakers habitually "backshift" in such contexts anyway, so the fact of backshifting itself doesn't inherently imply anything about whether the exam is *still* in the future at time of utterance.